# Create a custom divider in a layout

Tags: android, divider

I want to draw a custom divider in my layout. I know how to draw a straight line divider, but I want something similar to this:

[image: Criss-crossed line divider]

I want the criss-cross lines to be the divider and set the view's background to the same as how we would do it here:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Comment: Something similar to what?

Comment: Got it working by getting the image of one teeth of the zigzag, i.e. /\, and then repeating it via a bitmap as described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *tiled* xml bitmap.

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Comment: Is back a default drawable?

Comment: No. It's meant to be a repeatable segment of that zig-zag line.